# Need a list of modified files regardless of commit, to execute modified stored procedures in local DB. Best Practice for this in Git?

Tags: git, stored-procedures, svn, tortoisesvn, diff

My team recently migrated from Subversion (SVN) utilizing TortoiseSVN to Git, with GitHub. Our system is set up to use Visual Studio 2022 for an ASP.NET Web Forms project. We do track stored procedures in our version control, and we each have our own local DB for development. Previously, when we pulled an update in SVN, a nice popup with the summary of every changed file would appear, and we could then filter by the file extension and click and execute the file in SQL Server Management Studio to ensure that our databases were synced with production:  [image] The system actually worked pretty well. However, there doesn't appear to be a neat equivalent for git.

My coworker mentioned the possibility of utilizing TortoiseGIT (basically the GIT analog of TortoiseSVN) but unfortunately it does not appear there is a nice, clean, visual studio extension for this, but it may be our only option. It was difficult convincing the team to migrate to GIT in the first place, and I am really trying to minimize the disruption in everyone's workflow during this transition. SO, My question is: does anyone have any suggestions for when merge or a pull is performed, how can we get a nice clear cut log of all the files that were changed since the local working directory of the checked out branch was last synced, regardless of if they were changed over multiple commits on the remote?

Comment: You can get the list of files that changed between the position your `HEAD` _was_  and where it is _now_ (like, right after a merge/pull operation) with `git diff --name-status HEAD@{1}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this not because it's a bad question, as a question it's about as legit as they get, but because it's looking for tools, namely a decent VS Git plugin. Somebody please chime in with the right place to ask this, I'd like to know, but it's not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about CI/CD for databases.

I wouldn't recommend using git alone for this. Equally I would not recommend using TortoiseSVN. I doubt anyone ever intended your previous process, it was just what happened to work.

We happen to use RoundhousE; https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse, I don't even know if I'd recommend it but it works for us!

There are loads of options for this and I've seen teams roll their own. If you design your migrations a certain way then you can just run them all every time.

Few examples below.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-schema-compare-to-compare-different-database-definitions?view=sql-server-ver16
- https://www.liquibase.com/ci-cd
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli